# JavaScript won't fire execute on other computer

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

Currently, I have published a checkin program that allows my participants to checkin. The ASP.NET Website is setup with IIS and is able to be locally accessed. I wanted to use my computer as the main database and host for the website and then allow other computers, via LAN connection, access the site and sign people in. I am able to pull the site up on every computer, but I am unable to retrieve user data from the database. I am able to do it on my computer but no one else can when they connect. I see these errors on all the users computers that are connected:

[image: error image]

I can see that my Javascript is not firing on there side but on my side it is perfectly fine. Why is that I am getting that error? And how can I resolve it?

Comment: It's pretty obvious that some files aren't being loaded because they can't be found. This doesn't look like a Javascript problem, more like a server issue.

Comment: Do the people who access the site have internet, maybe you have a referenced library that can't download? If they don't have internet you will have to include those libraries as local resources in your project